# Responsive D3.js line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, charts, linechart

I am new to using D3 charts and am having an issue making my multi line chart responsive. I have reviewed some examples on how to make D3 responsive, but I can not make it work on my graph. If someone could assist me in making the code I currently have responsive I would really appreciate it.

Here is the code:

```
const svg = d3.select("#lineChart").attr("height", 400).attr("width", 850);

const width = +svg.attr("width");
const height = +svg.attr("height");

let hasMoreThan0 = false;

const render = (data) => {
  const xValue = (d) => d.dateTest;

  const yValue = (d) => d.total;

  const margin = { top: 60, right: 40, bottom: 88, left: 105 };
  const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
  const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  const xScale = d3
    .scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, xValue))
    .range([0, innerWidth])
    .nice();
  let yScale;

  let totalArray = [];
  data.forEach((element) => {
    totalArray.push(element.total);
  });
  const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
  let tc = totalArray.reduce(reducer);

  data.forEach((d) => {
    if (tc == 0) {
      yScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 51])
        .range([innerHeight, 0])
        .nice();
    } else {
      yScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, yValue))
        .range([innerHeight, 0])
        .nice();
    }
  });

  const g = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

  const xAxis = d3
    .axisBottom(xScale)
    .tickPadding(15)
    .ticks(d3.timeDay)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%a %d %B %y"));

  const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickSize(-innerWidth).tickPadding(10);

  const yAxisG = g.append("g").call(yAxis);
  yAxisG.selectAll(".domain").remove();

  yAxisG
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "axis-label")
    .attr("y", -60)
    .attr("x", -innerHeight / 2)
    .attr("fill", "black")
    .attr("transform", `rotate(-90)`)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

  const xAxisG = g
    .append("g")
    .call(xAxis)
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${innerHeight})`);

  xAxisG.select(".domain").remove();

  xAxisG
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "axis-label")
    .attr("y", 80)
    .attr("x", innerWidth / 2)
    .attr("fill", "black");

  const areaGenerator = d3
    .area()
    .x((d) => xScale(xValue(d)))
    .y0(innerHeight)
    .y1((d) => yScale(yValue(d)))
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

  g.append("path")
    .attr("class", "area-path")
    .attr("d", areaGenerator(data));

  const lineGenerator = d3
    .line()
    .x((d) => xScale(xValue(d)))
    .y((d) => yScale(yValue(d)))
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

  g.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line-path")
    .attr("d", lineGenerator(data));

  // g.append("text").attr("class", "title").attr("y", -10).text(title);
  svg.append("line").attr("class", "line-dashet");

  svg.append("line").attr("class", "line-dashet");

  svg
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
      return xScale(xValue(d)) + 105;
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
      return yScale(yValue(d)) + 60;
    })
    .attr("r", 4)
    .on("mouseout", function (e) {
      let toolTip = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip")[0];
      toolTip.classList.remove("tooltip-open");
    })
    .on("mouseover", function (e) {
      let selectPoint = d3.select(this);
      let xLineAnim = selectPoint._groups[0][0].cx.animVal.value;
      let yLineAnim = selectPoint._groups[0][0].cy.animVal.value;
      let selectPointData = selectPoint._groups[0][0].__data__;
      let dateFormated = formatDate(selectPointData.dateTest, a, "-");
      let toolTip = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip")[0];

      toolTip.style.top = yLineAnim - 55 + "px";
      toolTip.style.left = xLineAnim + 5 + "px";
      toolTip.innerHTML =
        "<div><span>Day: </span>" +
        dateFormated +
        "</div><div><span>Total: </span>" +
        selectPointData.total +
        "</div>";
      toolTip.classList.add("tooltip-open");

      svg
        .select(".line-dashet")
        .attr("x1", xLineAnim)
        .attr("y1", margin.top)
        .attr("x2", xLineAnim)
        .attr("y2", innerHeight + margin.top);
    });
};

getTimeData();
```